# Windows application build using flutter not working on every windows machine

Tags: windows, flutter, flutter-desktop

I am trying to build windows app using flutter. After successful build i have added **msvcp140.dll**, **vcruntime140.dll**, **vcruntime140_1.dll** as instructed. but still in some windows 10 and on all windows 7 machine it is crashing. Any suggestion what to do?

My release tree looks like follows:
build -> windows -> runner -> release

1. Data(Folder)
2. plugin(Folder)
3. bitsdojo_window_windows_plugin.lib
4. connectivity_plus_windows_plugin.dll
5. dart_vlc_plugin.dll
6. desktop_window_plugin.dll
7. flutter_windows.dll
8. msvcp140.dll
9. vcruntime140.dll
10. vcruntime140_1.dll
11. libvlc.dll
12. libvlccore.dll
13. App.exe
14. psg.exp
15. psg.lib
16. webview_windows_plugin.dll
17. WebView2Loader.dll

Comment: Please share all the files that you are distributing. If you really aren't missing any files, you likely have an issue with the application itself. If that ends up being the case, you need to debug it yourself to find what's causing the issue.

Comment: Please check my post. i have updated it. my application tree looks like the above.

Comment: You're going to have to do your own debugging here. If your application doesn't have any issues in debug mode, you're going to have to remove elements of your application bit by bit until your isolate the part causing your issue. Until then, there isn't much people here on SO can do since your application appears to be quite large.

Answer (score 2):

`bitsdojo_window` doesn't support all the versions of Windows that Flutter does. It [unconditionally links against APIs that are only present in newer versions of Windows 10](https://github.com/bitsdojo/bitsdojo_window/issues/53).

Comment: Thank you. After deleting the plugin and adjusting the code when i am trying to run on windows 7 it is saying 'api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll' missing.

Comment: You're using several other Windows plugins; have you checked all of those to see if they support Windows 7?

Comment: I have even tried with default flutter project (which is incrementing counter.) to run on windows 7. I am getting same DLL error.

Comment: If the default app doesn't run, you should file an issue with exact details of the error and the system you tried to run it on. (Perhaps the version of Windows 7 hasn't been updated enough for the VC++ redistributable to work, for instance.) Keep in mind that Windows 7 support is only best-effort.